# How to achieve this feature

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve a feature from this application (Please see video)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4VHP.jpg

I made an expo here for you to easily make a solution

https://snack.expo.io/HknL0ZCAS

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear at all what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this one:

https://snack.expo.io/H1rGEMRAr

I used 'state' to control what was inside of `emptyCircles`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      emptyCircles: [{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      }]
    };

    this.clearEmptyCircles = this.clearEmptyCircles.bind(this);
    this.addCircle = this.addCircle.bind(this);
  }
```

And wrote some functions to update that state:

```
  clearEmptyCircles() {
    this.setState({emptyCircles: [{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      },{
        image: placeholder,
      }]})
  }

  addCircle(image) {
    const list = this.state.emptyCircles.slice(0);
    const firstNonEmpty = list.find(p => !p.taken);
    if (firstNonEmpty) {
      firstNonEmpty.image = image;
      firstNonEmpty.taken = true;
    }
    this.setState({emptyCircles: list});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. One more question, how can i remove specific number on the taken empty circle? Like when i click on one of emptycircle, the number on that circle will be remove

Comment: I think you'll have to learn how React works my dude, it's all just a matter of updating the state via `this.setState` in your callbacks. You should know that `array.map` takes a second argument, index, which you can use in your onClick callback to change that particular index of the array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty beginner from programming and doing my best to learn things in Javascript and React

Comment: Ah, damn, React is pretty heavy to learn in my opinion if you're not already super comfortable with javascript.